# Amazon Quicksight Integration with React native integration throws Unhandled promise rejection, [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: HTMLElement]

Tags: javascript, react-native, amazon-quicksight, aws-sdk-js, quicksight-embedding

I'm trying to use amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk for the react native integration throws error " Unhandled promise rejection, [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: HTMLElement] ". Is it like the package not supported for react-native? Below is the code that i've been trying. The same code works for the react when div is used instead of View.

```
import * as QuickSightEmbedding from 'amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk';

embedDashboard = (embeddedurl, containerDiv) => {
    var dashboard;
    var options = {
    url: embeddedurl,
    container: containerDiv,
    scrolling: 'no',
    height: '700px',
    width: '1200px',
    locale: 'en-US',
    footerPaddingEnabled: true
    };
    dashboard = QuickSightEmbedding.embedDashboard(options);
    dashboard.on('error', this.onError);
    dashboard.on('load', this.onDashboardLoad);
    };

    componentDidMount() {
    this.embedDashboard(embeddedurl, this.dsr.current);
    }
    
    render(){
    return(
    <View ref={this.dsr} style={{ overflow: 'scroll', width: '100%' }} />
    )
    }
```

Is there an alternative package or suggestion for Amazon Quicksight Dashboard embedding with react-native?

Comment: yes you can not use react packages in react native

Comment: @NishargShah    It's just a javascript package that I've used here so i thought it should be applicable for react-native as well. Is there any alternative that you could suggest

Comment: no, you can not use any JS library as well, because it contains DOM and document stuff